# Good search box with product drop down filtering

Tags: jquery, search, datatables

I am thinking about changing over my current search facility to list out all the products on my website and then filter them based on what's typed in, so only showing the user products that exist underneath.

I've looked at datatables, but it looks like it would be quite intensive to have it search on each character ( I know I can put a 5 character limit on it ) and so I looked on Google and saw that a few people have implemented select2 ajaxing the data to do something similar.

Before I get started I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for which would be the better of the two, or if there is an alternative that I've not encountered?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using jquery autcomplete for this, and editing it further as I needed it. My main reason for going for it was that it  waits until the user had finished typing before doing a post request whereas both datatables and the select2 option did a post request on each letter typed no matter the speed of the typer.

Hopefully that will help someone else who's looking to do something similar!

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/